# Why jQuery return data is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my webpage I am using jQuery/Ajax to save form data. After save the data using php I am showing successful message like bellow :

```
if($sql){
    $sql_result[] =  "<div class='success'>updated</div>";
}

echo end($sql_result);
```

In Ajax return data I am checking a condition if message is contain `updated` then I will hide a html element but It's not working.

**Here is my jQuery code:**

```
function save_email (element, event) {

    e = $(element);
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData =  new FormData(e.parents('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({        
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType: false,
        processData : false,

        url : 'save_email.php', 
        type : 'POST',
        xhr : function () {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success : function (data) {
            $("#email_success").html(data);
            //$("#email_success").show('slow').delay(3000).hide('slow');              
            if(data == "<div class='success'>updated</div>" ) {                
                $("#save_email_button").hide('slow');                
                $(".delete_ex_email_label").hide('slow');                
            }            
        },
    });
}
```

**Console log data**

[image]

**Updated:**

`alert(data)` is showing this :

[image]

Comment: Don't send HTML from server, just send status/flag in JSON format and then on client side create HTML.

Comment: is that for quickly loading purpose @Tushar ?

Comment: Print in console `data` variable in success callback. What value it displays?

Comment: if you use what @Tushar said you can handle the situations easier and it also is a more beneficial structure.

Comment: php sometimes has extra whitespace in output text... comparing an html string like what you have try using `$.trim(data) === "<div class='success'>updated</div>")`. Even still it's simpler to use json and check a boolean property in an object vs matching  complex string

Comment: @roaiven check the update.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, It was white space issue. It's working now :)

Comment: @shibbirahmed in the future, instead of using `alert` function, use `console.log`. It would be better to debug this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not uncommon to end up with extra whitespace in php text/html output

That is one  reason it's easier to use json and check object properties , especially over comparing a complex string like you are doing.

However using trim() when comparing string results is generally a good idea

try

```
$.trim(data) === "<div class='success'>updated</div>")
```